# How to restore attached console prompt

Tags: c#, winapi, console

Using WinForms application, I would like it to show some help (when asked && started from console). In `Main`, I use kernel32's `AttachConsole(-1)`, write some info using standard `Console.WriteXXX(...)` and then kernel32's `FreeConsole()`.

**Problem:**
After the application exits, the standard console prompt (the current directory) is not restored, the cursor stays blinking on last line (written by the application). After pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the prompt is restored. It **seems like** the application waits until the key is pressed, but it does not, because any key press is interpreted already by the console.

Any tips what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944.aspx) when you `FreeConsole`? Or `DetachConsole` if you use `AttachConsole`?

Comment: Regarding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx `FreeConsole` is applicable to `AttachConsole` (if not called by the user, it is called automagically by the OS). There is nothing like `DetachConsole`.

Comment: You can argue, but how about trying `AllocConsole` instead of `AttachConsole` ([proof](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/68979/Attaching-a-Console-to-a-WinForms-application)) ;)

Comment: It allocates *new* console, I would like to utilize the existing console the user is using and starts the application from...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, thought you want to open another console window for help messages of your winform application. If your application is console application, then simply use [`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) you already have one.

Comment: It is not, primarily it is WinForms one, but this question is about the case the 'experienced' user fires the application from existing console. When fired by BFU's doubleclick on desktop or explorer no 'consoling' is performed.